# Simple Form javascript error message appears in wrong place

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, simple-form, jquery-select2

I am using simple form and jquery selextbox.  Everything is working fine, except the JavaScript error message (before form is submitted) that displays is not displaying next to the select box, but at the top left corner of the page(right next to the back button, even thought the form is right in the middle of the page).  I know it has something to do with select box, because if I remove select box, the error message is displayed in the right place.  Here is my form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="custom-select">
         <%= f.input :type, collection: ["Student", "Employer"], 
             include_blank: "What are you?", required: true, label: false, %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$('.custom-select select').c2Selectbox();
```

Here is the generated html without select box:

```
<div class="input select required user_type">
   <select id="user_type" class="select required" required="required" 
     name="user[type]" aria-required="true">
    <option value="Student"></option>
    <option value="Employer"></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

And here is the html generated with the selectbox:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <div class="input select required user_type">
        <select id="user_type" class="select required c2-sb-enabled" required="required" name="user[type]" aria-required="true" style="display: none;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Student"></option>
            <option value="Employer"></option>
        </select>
        <div class="c2-sb-wrap">
            <div class="c2-sb-inner-wrap">
                <div class="c2-sb-text" style="width: 64px;"></div>
                <a class="c2-sb-button" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="c2-sb-list-wrap" style="min-width: 382px;">
                <ul class="c2-sb-list"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I move the error message to the field, where simple form usually puts it by default?

Comment: What does the generated html look like before and after calling `c2Selectbox()`?

Comment: I just added it.  Thanks Jason

Comment: Can you show the html for the error and where it appears within the html/dom?

Comment: I don't know what the html for the error is.  Its generated automatically by simple form.